# Секция template во vue.js

Tags: vue.js, шаблоны

Есть несколько компонентов, у которых одинаковый код в секции `template`. Все компоненты - это однофайловые компоненты (**single file**). Существуют ли механизмы, позволяющие вынести секцию `template` во внешний файл и потом его подключить к компонентам?

```
<template>
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>текст</p>
</template>
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, хотя бы примерный код, как это выглядит у вас

Comment: @ДанилЧугаев Пожплуйста. Вопрос не в коде, а в оптимизации компоненты. Но, если это Вам как-то поможет, пожалуйста, код выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете поступить следующим образом: все что находится в `template` оформить отдельным компонентом, и вызывать его в нужных местах, а данные в него передавать через `props`. Пример:

```
//файл main.vue
<template>
  <div>
     <my-component :dataComponent="temp"></my-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import myComponent from './my_component.vue'

  export default {
     components: [myComponent],
     data () {
       return {
         temp: {
           a: 1,
           b: 2
         }
       }
     }
  }
</script>

//файл my_component.vue
<template>
  <div>
    {{dataComponent.a}} + {{dataComponent.b}} = 3
  </div>
</template>

<script>        
  export default {
    props: ['dataComponent']
  }
</script>
```

Про `props` можете почитать [в документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props)

P.S.: это очень упрощенный пример.

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Только тут проблема в том, что я вижу передаваемый аргумент в темплейте. Но если значение аргумента присваиваю переменной, то при передаче другого значения в параметре внутри компонента ничего не меняется. 

Напрмиер: 
передаю
`
//main.vue
<my-component :dataComponent="selectNavi"></my-component> 

methods: 
{
selectNavi: function (event) {
          this.naviName = event.currentTarget.innerText;
} `

В файле  **my_component.vue** могу вывести в секции **<template>** вот так: `<p>{{ dataComponent }}</p>`

Comment: Но вот этот код не показывает новое значение. Постоянно видно значение, которое было присвоено ему при первом рендеринге:

` created:
{
console.log(this.dataComponent)
} `

Comment: То что вы передаете `selectNavi` - это должен быть объект, а не функция)) тогда у вас будут видны обновления внутри компонента.

Comment: Приношу извинение. Передаю naviName. Т. е. код такой:
** <my-component :dataComponent="naviName"></my-component> **

Comment: Может быть функция вызывается 1 раз? Если делать через `v-model`, тогда значение в дочернем элементе однозначно будет изменяться. Посмотрите пример в документации про [динамические входные параметры](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: вся логика компонентов идеентичная за исключением одного, передаваемого параметра. И она (логика) так же вынесена в отдельный файл. Подключается через import

В template секции вижу изменение, а в коде тольеко то, которое при первом рендеринге передавалось. Такое впечатление, что код кэшируется.

Comment: **P. S. ** Решил задачу через computed. Отлавливаю там изменения. По другому ни как не получилось. Данил, спасибо за совет.

Comment: Только что хотел написать попробовать вам через `computed` =)) Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Ну или так

```
<template src="template.html"></template>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаете компонент test.vue
2. В main.js его импортируете
3. Объявляете компонент

> Vue.component('classname', test);

4. В test.vue пишите шаблонный код.
5. В родительском шаблоне объявляете `<classname></classname>`

Answer (score 0):

Если используется webpack, то шаблон можно объявить в отдельном файле и далее его импортировать:

template.html

```
<div>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>текст</p>
</div>
```

index.js

```
import template from './template.html';

export default {
    name: 'component_name',
    template
}
```

PS. Потребуется `html-loader`